# XML and XSL transformation

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt, tomcat7

On my tomcat I have a servlet at this address: `http://192.168.1.2/FirstApp/TestXslServlet` which generates the following XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./TestBean.xsl"?>

<TheRoot>
    <hw>Hello World!</hw>
</TheRoot>
```

I have the xsl here: `http://192.168.1.2/FirstApp/TestBean.xsl`
Which contains the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/TheRoot">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>XSL loaded!</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th><xsl:value-of select="hw"/></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I load the servlet all I see is "Hello World!", which is the same I see if I completely remove the xsl or if I put a dummy xsl name, so it appears that there is some problem with loading it. Why?

Both the XML and the XSL should be correct as I tested them on this website: http://markbucayan.appspot.com/xslt/index.html and the transformation went as expected.

EDIT: It appears to be working on explorer, but not on firefox, so the issue is browser-related.

EDIT2: I tried to download both files from firefox to test them locally, the servled downloaded as `TestXslServlet.xml` and the xsl downloaded as `TestBean.xsl.xml`. I renamed the xsl removing the ".xml" extension and now from the local disk it's working fine.
I tried to see if the firefox developer console could shed any light on what it's happening, if I reload the page on the server I get:

```
[11:01:39.325] GET http://192.168.1.2/FirstApp/TestXslServlet [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 32ms]
```

If I reload the page from the local disk I get:

```
[11:04:00.507] file:///C:/[...]/xsltest/TestBean.xsl
```

The MIME Type for TestBean.xsl is "application/xml" when loaded from the server and "text/xml" when loaded from the disk.
I tried to upload the exact same files that works on local to the server and they do not work (the difference is that I'm now calling a static `TestXslServlet.xml` instead of the servlet to generate the xml, the MIME type is "application/xml", as for the servlet).

EDIT3: In order to rule out any mistake on my part I tried to use the example files provided here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLT_in_Gecko/Basic_Example the page loads fine when loaded from the local disk but the transformation isn't applied when loaded from the server. It appears the be an issue with firefox(v.25) and tomcat(v.7) however the MIME type seems correct to me, from firefox's "page info" it shows "application/xml" for both (when loaded from the server, there is no MIME type information when loaded from local disk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer here: [Firefox 3 doesn't apply my xslt stylesheet, but other browsers do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221434/firefox-3-doesnt-apply-my-xslt-stylesheet-but-other-browsers-do)

The "NoScript" plugin for firefox prevents XSL Trasformation...

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is indeed well-formed, and your XSLT does run, when properly invoked.

I'd guess that your Tomcat server is serving FirstApp/TestXslServlet with a non-XML MIME type.  If you want a browser to run the associated XSLT stylesheet on a Web resource, then you want it to be served as text/xml or application/xml (many authorities prefer the latter, which suggests they think XML is not human-readable text; I prefer the former), or some other MIME type which browsers recognize as XML and for which they will invoke <del>a browser</del> *an XML parser and XSLT processor* [Thanks to LarsH for spotting the typo].  At a guess, your configuration defaults to serving your servlet output as text/html.

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer. However I wonder if the last occurrence of 'browser' is a typo. Browsers will invoke a browser? Maybe, 'an XSLT processor' was intended?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't solve it, the mime type is already application/xml. I tried to set it to text/xml but it didn't changed anything.
However I just realized that it works in explorer but not in firefox so the issue seems to be browser-related, I'll update the question.